# SoundCloud API and 401 Error for registered application

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, soundcloud

I have a problem with SoundCloud API in my application.
I have created an app, what get link to the track (e.g. something like this http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/48760960) and get stream_url, what later can be played using SCAudioStream. There is no auth for users, I use only client id and client secret of my app. App is registered.

I create soundCloudManager this way:

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        conf = [SCSoundCloudAPIConfiguration configurationForProductionWithClientID: kSCClientID
                                                                       clientSecret: kSCClientSecret
                                                                        redirectURL: kSCRedirectURL];
        conf.accessTokenURL = kSCAccessTokenURL;
        api = [[SCSoundCloudAPI alloc] initWithDelegate: self 
                                 authenticationDelegate: self 
                                       apiConfiguration: conf];
       //[api checkAuthentication];
    }
    return self;
}
```

If uncomment [api checkAuthentication], then logs will says next:

"auth ready with URL:https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=&redirect_uri=&response_type=code"

Then I call this method to get data from track:

```
- (void)runSearchingStreamWithTrackID: (NSString *)trackID
{
    [api performMethod: @"GET" 
            onResource: @"tracks" 
        withParameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:trackID forKey:@"ids"] 
               context: @"trackid" 
              userInfo: nil];
}
```

And then this delegate's method calls:

```
- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
     didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo
```

Text of error:

"HTTP Error: 401".

It means unauthorized. But why? Should I be authorized as soundCloud user to getting info about tracks?

I'm using this for SoundCloudAPI:
https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper

Please, help! :(

---

Today I fixed it. I just add this method to init :

```
[api authenticateWithUsername:kLogin password:kPwd];
```

After it this method was called:

```
- (void)soundCloudAPIDidAuthenticate
```

So, this test account was authorized.

Then I call this method:

```
- (void)runSearchingStreamWithTrackID: (NSString *)trackID
{
    [api performMethod: @"GET" 
            onResource: @"tracks" 
        withParameters: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:trackID forKey:@"ids"] 
               context: @"trackid" 
              userInfo: nil];
}
```

And no one of these methods will be called:

```
- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
     didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo;
- (void)soundCloudAPI:(SCSoundCloudAPI *)soundCloudAPI 
    didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data 
              context:(id)context 
             userInfo:(id)userInfo;
- (void)soundCloudAPIDidAuthenticate;
- (void)soundCloudAPIDidResetAuthentication;
- (void)soundCloudAPIDidFailToGetAccessTokenWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)soundCloudAPIPreparedAuthorizationURL:(NSURL *)authorizationURL;
```

But there is log:

```
-[NXOAuth2PostBodyStream open] Stream has been reopened after close
```

And this method was called:

```
[NXOAuth2Client oauthConnection:connection didFailWithError:error];
error: HTTP 401
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understood the problem. Just download the SC API from the official site and install the latest SC API. Then do something like this:

```
- (void)searchStreamURLByTrackID: (NSString *)trackID
{
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/%@.json?client_id=%@", trackID, kSCClientID];

[SCRequest performMethod: SCRequestMethodGET 
              onResource: [NSURL URLWithString:string]
         usingParameters: nil 
             withAccount: nil
  sendingProgressHandler: nil 
         responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                                      NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSLog(@"FOUND:\n%@", resultString);
                              }
                      ];
```

}

After that obtain the stream url from the JSON in the resultString.

Finally, you have to write this code:

```
NSString *streamURL = [(NSDictionary *)jsonData objectForKey:@"stream_url"];
NSString *realURL = [streamURL stringByAppendingFormat:@".json?client_id=%@", kSCClientID];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:realURL]];
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI ?
This is the more current version of the API wrapper (if you don't need iOS 3.0 support).
It also comes with a tutorial video: http://vimeo.com/28715664

If you want to stay with this library you should try to figure out where the log message ("auth ready with ...") appears. Did you implement any of the AuthorizationDelegate methods?
See https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md#the-authentication-delegate-the-easy-way

Comment: Now I,m trying to implement CocoaSoundCloudAPI, which suggested me. 
I did all steps from docs, but faces this error:

Automatic Reference Counting:
No known class method for selector 'JSONObjectWithData:options:error:'

I tried to disable arc, but it didn't help.